# Why is there an Statment Error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, create-table

I have following Statment in MySQL and become every time this error(Screenshot):

```
CREATE TABLE orderstatus
(
    OStatusID int NOT null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    OStatus varchar(30) null
(
```

I dont know why I become this error

Can you help me, please?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTfhE.png)

Comment: in SQLFiddle no error is shown

Comment: Please try to translate the error message to English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the close bracket is wrong, it should be ')'

Comment: omg :) my brain... thank you

Comment: youre welcome, don't forget to put semicolon as well

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE orderstatus 
( 
   OStatusID int NOT null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   OStatus varchar(30) null 
)
```

Comment: isn't work, im sorry

Comment: this is the only one statment that isnt work in my code....

Comment: are you sure its not working? should be working because i already test it in phpmyadmin

Comment: In my code is this statment for example: CREATE TABLE kategorie
(
  KatID int NOT null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Kategorie varchar(30) null
)

Comment: And this statement are working fine.

Comment: in your post, you are using wrong bracket '('. it should be ')', compare with my post

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Below is right code Tested Successfully..

```
CREATE TABLE orderstatus 
( 
OStatusID int NOT null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
OStatus varchar(30) null 
)[enter image description here][1]
```